# How can I get route attributes dotnet core 3?

Tags: c#, .net-core, authorization, .net-core-3.0, routedata

I have upgraded dotnet core 2.2 to 3.preview 7.
So after that, I can't get custom attributes.
`context.Resource` in version 2.2 was type of `AuthorizationFilterContext`, but in version 3 is type of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Endpoint`.

Now I couldn't get attributes from endpoint.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Gamma.Core.Security
{
    public abstract class AttributeAuthorizationHandler<TRequirement,     TAttribute>
    : AuthorizationHandler<TRequirement> where TRequirement
    : IAuthorizationRequirement where TAttribute : Attribute
    {
        Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor = null;
        public AttributeAuthorizationHandler(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        }
        protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, TRequirement requirement)
        {
            var attributes = new List<TAttribute>();

            var action = (context.Resource as AuthorizationFilterContext)?.ActionDescriptor as ControllerActionDescriptor;
            if (context.Resource is Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Endpoint endpoint)
            {
                //endpoint.
            }

            if (action != null)
            {
                attributes.AddRange(GetAttributes(action.MethodInfo));
            }

            return HandleRequirementAsync(context, requirement, attributes);
        }

        protected abstract Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, TRequirement requirement, IEnumerable<TAttribute> attributes);

        private static IEnumerable<TAttribute> GetAttributes(MemberInfo memberInfo)
        {
            return memberInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TAttribute), false).Cast<TAttribute>();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I was able to get custom attributes in .NET Core 3.1 from `AuthorizationHandlerContext` using `ControllerActionDescriptor` in [Brian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58504298/12858798).

```cs
private IEnumerable<TAttribute> GetAttributes<TAttribute>(AuthorizationHandlerContext authContext)
{
    if (authContext.Resource is RouteEndpoint routeEndpoint)
    {
        var actionDescriptor = routeEndpoint.Metadata.OfType<ControllerActionDescriptor>().SingleOrDefault();
        var attributes = actionDescriptor?.MethodInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TAttribute), false).Cast<TAttribute>();
        return attributes;
    }
    
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since .net 5, context is `HttpContext`

There is [`GetEndPoint` method extension on `HttpContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.endpointhttpcontextextensions.getendpoint?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

```
protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, TRequirement requirement)
{
    if(context is HttpContext httContext){
        var endpoint = context.GetEndPoint();
    } else {
        throw ... // let's see how things will move with next version of .net 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not found the answer yet, but this might help:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-3.0 has a section "Accessing MVC request context in handlers", but this is wrong.

However under "Feedback" theirs 2 questions that look relevant with the most promising answer saying to add the code below to the `AuthorizationHandler`.

This gives access to `controllerActionDescriptor`, but as you can see I have looked at various property's but none give me the current routing data:

```
var controllerActionDescriptor = routeEndpoint.Metadata
    .OfType<ControllerActionDescriptor>()
    .SingleOrDefault();

if (controllerActionDescriptor != null)
{
    var a = controllerActionDescriptor.AttributeRouteInfo;
    var p = controllerActionDescriptor.Parameters;
    var ep = controllerActionDescriptor.EndpointMetadata;
    var r = controllerActionDescriptor.RouteValues;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I have found a solution,in ConfigureServices register an IHttpContextAccessor into IOC

```
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

then get it in AttributeAuthorizationHandler

```
public class AccountLoginAuthorizeHandler : AttributeAuthorizationHandler<AccountLoginAuthorizationRequirement, AccountLoginAttribute>
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
    public PermissionAuthorizeHandler(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, IZaabeeRedisClient redisClient,
    IOptions<LoginConfig> loginConfig)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(httpContextAccessor));
    }
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, AccountLoginAuthorizationRequirement requirement, IEnumerable<AccountLoginAttribute> attributes)
    {
        if (context.Resource is AuthorizationFilterContext filterContext)
        {
            var httpContext = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
            //Do Something
        }
        else
            //Do Something

        context.Succeed(requirement);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Comment: This will add unnecessary overhead.